# JPA entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() in a getter, when to cache/reuse?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have an abstract method that needs to be implemented, and return an entityManager.

Normally, with Spring you can inject an enititymanager using persistence context, however, I do not have this option now.

I have access to the entitymanagerfactory, but I do not really want the getEntityManager to return a new instance for every invokation. Sometimes, this method might be called several times from the same method, so I would like to see some caching principle.

I believe that Spring does not return a new instance either. Even though I am @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entitymanager;

So how should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) storage to cache the first retrieved EntityManager.

Just make sure you [clear the storage](http://naildrivin5.com/blog/2008/05/14/using-threadlocal-and-servlet-filters-to-cleanly-access-jpa-an-entitymanager.html) once you get out of your transaction boundary.

Comment: do you know how long an entitymanager can be shared? Do you need a entitymanager per transaction and commit/flush or can the entitymanager likely be shared across several transactions and commits?

Comment: You can have both scenarios. The second option is possible in Java EE when using an extended persistence context.